# ganeti network: change bridge name

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, bridge, ganeti

I try to add an instance to network, first first I need to connect the network to a bridge. I'm using bridge `vbr0` instead of standard `xen-br0`, `gnt-cluster info` shows that ganeti has the default set properly.

```
# gnt-network list
Network Subnet          Gateway      MacPrefix GroupList Tags
net1    192.168.18.0/24 192.168.18.1 -                   nfdhcpd
# gnt-network connect net1 default 
# gnt-network list
Network Subnet          Gateway      MacPrefix GroupList                    Tags
net1    192.168.18.0/24 192.168.18.1 -         default (bridged, xen-br0, ) nfdhcpd
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/2.12/html/man-gnt-network.html#connect), `gnt-network connect` no longer accepts mode and link.

**Notes:**

- Debian stable, ganeti v2.12.4.
- KVM
- gnt-cluster  info:
  Default nic parameters: 
    default: 
     link: vbr0
     mode: bridged
     vlan:
- [Issue 897](https://code.google.com/p/ganeti/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Opened%20Modified%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=897) but this should be already fixed..

**Questions:**

1. Why ganeti uses `xen-br0` instead of my default `vbr0`?
2. How can I change the bridge name in `gnt-network`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Why? Because it's a bug in ganeti
2. `gnt-network connect -N link=vbr0 net1 default`